# No internet after installing hyper-v

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I did a boo boo. My home lab machine running Windows Server 2016 got reinstalled here the other day and it had internet access thru the one physical ethernet connection.

Then I installed Hyper-V which installed a second adapter, virtual switch, and then the Hyper-V machine host does not have internet access anymore.

However, my VMs does :D

Any clue on what I did wrong? I need internet access on both host and virtual machines.

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You do not even come close to give half the information needed to start analyzing where your network topology is borked.

Answer (score 2):

Check the "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter" option in your Virtual Switch Properties.

[image]

Comment: I got this setting :-/

Comment: I would suggest that you remove all virtual switches in Hyper-V and that should restore network connectivity to the host (or allow you to correct the resulting network adapter setting on the host to restore network).  One you have that working again then follow the above advice by adding one virtual switch with that setting enabled.  Hyper-V will then edit your host adapter settings to work between the host and guest.